# Groupby selecting certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I follow the example here: (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply)

**Data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo"],
        "B": ["one", "one", "two", "three", "two", "two", "one", "three"],
        "C": np.random.randn(8),
        "D": np.random.randn(8),
    }
)
```

**Groupby 'A' but selecting on column 'C', then perform apply**

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')['C']

def f(group):
    return pd.DataFrame({'original': group,
                         'demeaned': group - group.mean()})

grouped.apply(f)
```

Everything is ok, but when I try with groupby'A' and selecting column 'C' and 'D', I cannot succeed in doing so:

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')[['C', 'D']]

for name, val in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(val)

grouped.apply(f)
```

So what do I do wrong here?

Thank you
Phan

Comment: do you get error? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: for single column it gives `pandas.Series` but for many columns it gives `pandas.DataFrame` - so it needs changes in `f()` - like `'original_C': group['C'], 'original_D': group['D'], ...`

Answer (score 2):

When you get single column (`['C']`) then it gives `pandas.Series`, but when you get many columns (`[ ['C', 'D'] ]`) then it gives `pandas.DataFrame` - and this need different code in `f()`

It could be

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')[['C', 'D']]

def f(group):
    return pd.DataFrame({
                'original_C': group['C'],
                'original_D': group['D'],
                'demeaned_C': group['C'] - group['C'].mean(),
                'demeaned_D': group['D'] - group['D'].mean(),
           })

grouped.apply(f)
```

Result:

```
   original_C  original_D  demeaned_C  demeaned_D
0   -0.122789    0.216775   -0.611724    1.085802
1   -0.500153    0.912777   -0.293509    0.210248
2    0.875879   -1.582470    0.386944   -0.713443
3   -0.250717    1.770375   -0.044073    1.067846
4    1.261891    0.177318    0.772956    1.046345
5    0.130939   -0.575565    0.337582   -1.278094
6   -1.121481   -0.964481   -1.610417   -0.095454
7    1.551176   -2.192277    1.062241   -1.323250
```

---

Because with two columns you already have `DataFrame` so you can also write it shorter without converting to `pd.DataFrame()`

```
def f(group):
    group[['demeaned_C', 'demeaned_D']] = group - group.mean()

    return group
```

or more universal

```
def f(group):
    for col in group.columns:
        group[f'demeaned_{col}'] = group[col] - group[col].mean()

    return group
```

---

**BTW:**

If you use `[ ['C'] ]` instead of `['C']` then you also get `DataFrame` instead of `Series` and you can use last version of `f()`.

Comment: i didn't test this, but i think you can also do `return group.sub(group.mean()).add_prefix('demeaned_')`

Comment: @tdy I tested it - it gives correct values but `add_prefix()` creates `DataFrame` with new index which has 2 levels - first level uses value `"foo", "bar"` from column A and second level use original index. And this puts rows in different order - first all rows for `foo`, next all rows for `bar`. The same result I got with `.rename(columns=lambda name:f'demeaned_{name}')`. At this moment I don't have idea how to change it.